# Regular expression for patterns repeating with comma (or white space)

Tags: regex

I want to validate a phrase containing a list of specific words separated by comma or white space. The list of words can be `[A-E]\d` and `(ST|st)\d` (as regular expressions). So a valid phrase would be:

`A1, a2, B1, ST1, st3,c3,e4   ,   st6`

While `A11, G2,stt3` would not be.

I came up with this regex:

```
^([A-E|a-e])?(?(1)\d|(?:ST|st)\d)(?:[\s,]+([A-E|a-e])?(?(2)\d|(ST|st)\d))*$
```

But it doesn't always succeed. While `b3, st2, a3, st3` succeeds, `b3, st2, a3, st3` fails.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following pattern with the `i` flag for case-insensitive matching:

```regex
^(?:[A-E]|ST)\d(?:\s*,\s*(?:[A-E]|ST)\d)+$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IKMUSi/1)**.

**Details:**

```
^                   # Beginning of the string/line.
(?:[A-E]|ST)        # Match either a single letter between 'A and 'E' or 'ST'.
\d                  # Match a single digit.
(?:                 # Beginning of a non-capturing group.
    \s*,\s*         # Match a single comma surrounded by optional whitespace characters.
    (?:[A-E]|ST)\d  # Either a letter between 'A and 'E' or 'ST' followed by a digit.
)                   # End of the non-capturing group.
+                   # Match the previous group between one and unlimited times.
$                   # End of the string/line.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 # demo https://regex101.com/r/hi6eWn/1     
 # ^\s*(?:[A-Ea-e]|ST|st)\d(?:\s*,\s*(?:[A-Ea-e]|ST|st)\d)*\s*$
 
 ^                             # BOL
 \s*                           # wsp, opt
 (?: [A-Ea-e] | ST | st )      # The letter part, core word
 \d                            # The digit part, core word
 (?:                           # Trailing CSV core parts, opt
    \s* , \s* 
    (?: [A-Ea-e] | ST | st )
    \d 
 )*
 \s*                           # wsp, opt
 $                             # EOL
```